# Unable to download plugins for vim on windows10

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am trying to download plugins for vim on my windows 10 and I having an issue where vim is not recognizing the functions "call plug#begin()" and "call plug#end()"

my _vimrc file is in the following directory: C:\Users\omarh

I searched this issue and it seems like the reason is the location of the file "plug.vim"

I downloaded this file into: C:\Users\omarh\Vim\vim82\autoload

I even copied the file into another directory: C:\Users\omarh\Vim\autoload

However the program still doesn't recognize these functions or some commands, such as, "PlugInstall"

Answer (score 0):

*All* your Vim configuration is supposed to happen in a `vimfiles` directory located at the root of your `$HOME`:

```
C:\Users\omarh\vimfiles\
```

That `plug.vim` file you downloaded should be here:

```
C:\Users\omarh\vimfiles\autoload\plug.vim
```

And it is recommended to also move your `_vimrc` there (note the name change: `_vimrc` becomes `vimrc`, without the leading underscore):

```
C:\Users\omarh\vimfiles\vimrc
```

Comment: It seems like that is still not working. When I changed the _vimrc to vimrc and put it in the directory you mentioned above, the program did not apply the changes there and just kind of ignored it. However, when I moved it back the root, it works. the plug.vim is not being recognized, whether it is in the root, or in the directory you specified.

Comment: Did you restart Vim?